# Python tuple execution - conditional statements

Tags: python, conditional-statements

I am a bit confused about how tuples are executed in python especially with conditional statements.
Here is the code

```
one = 1
two = 2
three = 3
four = 4
five = 5
six = 6

if (one, two, three) < (four, one, six):
    print("Bilal rashid 123")
else:
    print("rashid")
```

I think the overall output should be False but instead it is true. Below is a picture of what statments I think should be true:[image]

Can someone please explain how this execution works?

Comment: You are asking how tuples are *ordered*, i.e how they behave when you use `<` and the like on them. Well, they are ordered lexicographically, like other sequences (str, list)

Comment: that is kinda of confusing because I am not understanding that out of the three statements 2 of them are true and one is false so should that not return False overall?

Comment: It's the same way alphabetical order works (hence the name "lexicographical"). `"apple" < "bag"` because `"a" < "b"`; it doesn't matter that `"p" > "a"` and `"p" > "g"`.

Comment: @mirratrashid please see the linked duplicate. Also, read about lexicographic ordering (which is sort of a generalization of alphabetical ordering)